# What means sub-cycled?

Tags: c++

In method run() of class Time is used variable bool subCycling_ in the following code:

```
       bool Foam::Time::run() const
  810 {
  811     bool running = value() < (endTime_ - 0.5*deltaT_);
  812 
  813     if (!subCycling_) //bool subCycling_; //- Is the time currently being sub-cycled?
  814     {
  815         // only execute when the condition is no longer true
  816         // ie, when exiting the control loop
  817         if (!running && timeIndex_ != startTimeIndex_)
  818         {
  819             // Note, end() also calls an indirect start() as required
  820             functionObjects_.end();
  821         }
  822     }
  823 
  824     if (running)
  825     {
  826         if (!subCycling_)
  827         {
  828             const_cast<Time&>(*this).readModifiedObjects();
  829 
  830             if (timeIndex_ == startTimeIndex_)
  831             {
  832                 functionObjects_.start();
  833             }
  834             else
  835             {
  836                 functionObjects_.execute();
  837             }
  838         }
  839 
  840         // Update the "running" status following the
  841         // possible side-effects from functionObjects
  842         running = value() < (endTime_ - 0.5*deltaT_);
  843     }
  844 
  845     return running;
  846 }
  847 
  848 
  849 bool Foam::Time::loop()
  850 {
  851     bool running = run();
  852 
  853     if (running)
  854     {
  855         operator++();
  856     }
  857 
  858     return running;
  859 }
```

When I translate sub-cycled into German I still don't get the meaning.
So, what means sub-cycled [line 813] ? An example would be great here.

greetings 
streight

Comment: It seems like it's just a boolean variable...

Comment: It doesn't make much sense in English either. If the author didn't document it, you'll need to read the code in the `if` statement, and figure out what that does, to know what he meant.

Comment: @Soylent: Sure, but I need to know the meaning behind the variable.

Comment: @Mike: Ok, I posted the question, because I hoped some programmers came across the term "sub-cycled" before.

Comment: I would start solving this problem by essentially doing what Mike said - research.  I would perform a search on the entire project(s) for the string "subCycling".  Then I could see where it's being used, where it's defined, etc.  This should provide me a better idea of what the original intent was, why it is still being used, and what it is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to ask the person who wrote the code. It is impossible to randomly tell from this tiny code snippet without any context. There may be a hint in the lines that follow (as those are the lines affected by this boolean), but you didn't show us those.

However, as a clue, some timer implementations use "sub-cycle" to describe running repeated iterations of a timer mechanism, within each cycle of the primary event loop. This can resolve contention caused by individual wait conditions:

- http://tams-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/applets/hades/webdemos/72-pic/60-swatch/swatch.html
- http://nute.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Lockets/Tears/tears_fmw/main.cpp
- http://www.google.com/patents/US2530622

It's more often found in code that runs mechanical devices.

Comment: Ok, I already posted this question about a week ago in the OpenFOAM forum, but no answer yet. Just wanted to give it a try here, perhaps someone already worked with it and therefore could have a clue.